# How to display pretty fractions in Crystal Reports generated PDF

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, fractions

I'm exporting a report to PDF using Crystal Reports bundled with VS2008.  I need to display non-standard fractions so that they look nice instead of just something like 26/32. I have turned html interpretation on for the field so `&frac12;` and other standard html fraction entities display nicely, however, because CR does not understand `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags I cannot format non-standard fractions to look pretty.  Anyone have any ideas?

** edit **

The fractions I'm displaying are passed to the Crystal Report as a string via a dataset in the format "xx/yy" or "xx yy/zz" and represent a product dimension.  After thinking about it some more I could probably pass the numerator and the denominator as separate fields and format them in the report that way, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way.

Comment: 1) Can you give an example of the type of fraction you would be displaying? (stock value, cooking measurements) What is the data source? (decimal->fraction? numerator and denominator separately?)

Comment: Actually, ren33, I think your solution is already as elegant as you can get.

Comment: I was afraid someone would say that. I guess I'll have to use that method for now and start looking for a better, non-CR reporting solution later. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work, but I'll throw it out there anyway.

You can try to use inline styles instead of `<sup>` or `<sub>`. vertical-align allows a value of sub or super.

Example:

```
<td style="vertical-align:sub"> ... </td>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this out since Crystal does support some inline styling, but unfortunately CR doesn't respect the vertical-align. Didn't work when I adjusted margin or padding either. I did change the font size so the fraction looks better but still not perfect. Will keep experimenting with this line of thought.  Thanks Dusty.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my posting [Crystal Reports: DecimalToFraction() Function](http://www.cogniza.com/blog/?p=7)